# How to add a class in ' li ' on hover over and also add a class which is not hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I add a class when hovering over a list and also need to add another class to the list which is not hovered upon.

I need to hide the elements which is not hovered for the spacing problem.

Below is my code:

```
$('#menu').on('mouseover', '> li', function(e) {
    # attach hover event to the menu, and check which LI you are hovering
    if (!$(this).hasClass('.current)')) {
        $('.current', '#menu').removeClass('active');
    }
}).on('mouseout', '> li', function (e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('.current)')) {
        $('.current', '#menu').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML as well, make a snippet please

Comment: it is too large to be post. Can you please check it from the website that I have given already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your question I only understood this, if needed result is something else, please let me know.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').hover(function(){
      $("li").addClass("notHovered")
      $(this).addClass('hovered')
  },function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hovered')
    $("li").removeClass("notHovered")
  });
});
```

```css
.notHovered {
  color: red;
}

.hovered {
  color: green;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```